# USB3.0 Shield connection

Tags: usb, connector, shielding, footprint

In the below image for Amphenol GSB343K33HR, do the 4 rectangular pads in the center of the image signify Shield connections?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the drawing of the connector, yes, those would be shield connections. Those four pads would require solder paste to improve the mechanical connection of the connector to the PCB beyond that provided by the two soldered posts.